# UITableView edit mode strange behaviour under iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

Under iOS <=6:
When I click round switch, the delete "Usun" button goes from right.

[image: UITableView edit mode iOS <= 6]

In iOS 7: the cell goes to the left, delete "Usun" button is hidden, but work!!! after click.

[image: UITableView edit mode iOS > 6]

This is the same code & the same xib like in 6.

How can I resolve this problem under iOS 7?

Comment: See https://devforums.apple.com/message/873321#873321

Comment: @rmaddy big thx. I love you iOS.